# "Primarily Opinion Based" vs "Off Topic"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The "Primarily Opinion Based" close reason describes itself as

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Meanwhile, one of the "Off-topic" close reasons is described as

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

To me, these seem to be very similar, and I often find myself wondering which one I should be using under given circumstances. In the course of closing questions, when should I favor one of these reasons over the other?

Comment: Yeah, there is some natural overlap. It honestly doesn't matter which one you pick, so don't agonize too much over it.

Comment: *votes to close this question as primarily opinion based, because the other option isn't available on Meta* </s>

Comment: If the user asks something along the lines of "Which do you prefer, x or y?"., you go with the former. If the user is asking for us to recommend to find a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource, you pick the latter.

Comment: If [custom close reasons in other categories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons) are ever made possible, this will probably be one of the first changes made.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The tool request reason can be thought of as a subset of "primarily opinion based".  Once upon a time all tool requests were closed as being subjective and opinion based, but because tool requests ended up making a sufficiently large subset of those types of questions, it was eventually given it's own reason so that more specific information can be given to the author as to why those questions aren't allowed here.  You should prefer that reason for any questions that are requesting tools, even though "primarily opinion based" technically also applies, so that they can get this more targeted information.

Comment: I'd suggest that not all Tool Requests *are* opinion-based - "find a tool that does X" can have fact-based (though still off-topic) answers - "tools Y and Z both do X".

Comment: @PaulRoub They *can* have fact based answers.  They don't.  They end up being opinionated discussions in actual practice, so the close reason *does* apply, not that it matters any way given that there's a more applicable close reason regardless.